# How to add a list of a values that are in one table to another in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to merge some data that I have in two different Data frames

Here are my two data frames

I have a set of a client data in x that has an initials columns that I manually inserted, and another data frame called y,with only the ID & Initials

x has 2959 observations and y  has 978 observations, so I don't have all initials for all my clients in data frame x, but those that I do are in data frame y. And in data y, there are some NAs as well.

I want to create a new data frame that has all 2959 observations and has the initials filled in for the clients whose initials I do have in data frame y. Those who are not in data frame y I need to still have them in the final list but just with an NA. 
x

```
ID       Name      Initials     AGE 
123      Mike        NA          18
124      John        NA          20
125      Lily        NA          21
126      Jasper      NA          24
127      Toby        NA          27 
128      Will        NA          19 
129      OScar       NA          32
~~
~~
y 
~~
ID      Initials 
123       MC
126       TR
127       WO
129       NA
~~
~~


Here is my desired output


ID       Name      Initials     AGE 
123      Mike        MC          18
124      John        NA          20
125      Lily        NA          21
126      Jasper      NA          24
127      Toby        TR          27 
128      Will        WO          19 
129      Oscar       NA          32
```

I tried this, but the output only has 878 observations.

```
merge_data <- merge(x, y, 
                by = "ID")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `left_join` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x %>% 
               select(-Initials), y, by = 'ID')
```

---

In `base R`, by default it returns an inner join output, if we need `left_join`, specify `all.x = TRUE`

```
merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE, by = 'ID')
```